# What are the correct parameters of usage for addressing parties as one’s “learned friend”?

Tags: legal-terms, common-law, rules-of-court, barristers, rights-of-audience

Does a solicitor with right of audience address their opposing barrister as their learned friend? Do they get addressed as the barrister’s learned friend?

What of a litigant in person?

And in all cases is it to be used in place of all other terms of first or third person address? Or just sprinkled in occasionally amid other references to “you,” or “he/him,” or “Mr. Smith”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default way to address opponents in courtroom, no matter whether barristers, solicitors or lay litigants, is "<title> <surname>" e.g. Mr Smith.

"Learned friend" is just an alternative to be "sprinkled in occasionally". The "learned" bit was originally intended to denote that the opponent is highly educated in law and qualified to be representing people before the court. "Friend" denotes that the opponent is a member of the same profession or, otherwise, is civilized, reasonable, polite and adequate person to speak to about the contentious matters at issue (as opposed to what the actual opposing party would likely have been).

That said, strictly speaking, "learned friend" is only suitable for lawyers to verbally address each other in courtroom. But this is not a rule that is expected to be strictly followed. Indeed, I, while being a self-represented lay party, was actually addressed "my learned friend" by the opposing lawyer. I don't know whether it was a very subtle taunt/sarcasm or genuine appreciation, but either way, there was no disapproval by the judge.

Comment: Your use of *learnt* is intriguing. It's used in other circumstances too, eg between members of the UK Parliament when speaking of another member who is a lawyer, but there and elsewhere it's always been "learn-ed" meaning "wise; educated; having learnt stuff" rather than "learnt" (the stuff which is absorbed). Thus while the spelling *learnt* can be interchangeable with *learned,* here it generally isn't, because the pronunciation "learn-ed" is important. Perhaps practice is changing and what I listen to hasn't caught up.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Didn't know the subtle difference. I just checked my hearing transcript from the court and it is indeed "learned" not "learnt". Thanks!